# Will White Sand ever be released officially as a book?

Tags: cosmere, white-sand

*Arcanum Unbounded* has the prologue from the 1999 version of *White Sand*. I started *White Sand* and didn’t really like the comic book form. Does Brandon Sanderson intend to ever publish a canon, full written version of *White Sand*, or will it only officially ever be in graphic novel form?

Answer (score 4):

Possibly.

> Brandon:
>    It's possible that someday I will. So if you wanna be patient, maybe we'll do some Dragonsteel Edition, or something like that.

https://wob.coppermind.net/events/355/#e10687

Comment: Worth pointing out that the White Sand he is talking about here is what is often called "White Sand Prose", and as mentioned in the full quote that is taken from, has been released to members of Brandon's mailing list.  I don't know if it still gets sent out; but the text version of White Sand is already out there; just not as "official canon" as far as I know.  I'm not sure if the release he's talking about here would be canon either; or just a professionally published version of the White Sand prose.

Comment: @JMac It apparently contradicts the graphic novel; I heard the main character is female in the prose version, so it’s not exactly canon

Comment: @Stormblessed - Not quite, the LEO character is male in the prose but female in the published work.